# What I'm doing wrong with `data.filter`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm tryin to filter data with `data.filter()` because I need to find the elements that isn't equal to `0`, until here it's filtering the data in a correct way:

**CODE**

```
 this.tax = data.filter((item) =>item.value_tax != 0)
                .map((item) => +item.value_tax )
                .reduce((acc, obj) => acc +
               (
                  (((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity)) - ((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity) * Number(obj.discount)) / 100)) * Number(obj.calculate_tax))
               ) 
               -
               (
                  (((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity)) - (Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity) * Number(obj.discount)) / 100))
               ),
              0);
    console.log("Tax: ", this.tax)
```

**RESULT CONSOLE**

```
Tax:  
(3) […]
​
0: Object { id_factura_pivote: "1", cantidad_factura_pivote: "3", fecha_factura_pivote: "2018-09-14", … }
​
1: Object { id_factura_pivote: "5", cantidad_factura_pivote: "20", fecha_factura_pivote: "2018-09-14", … }
​
2: Object { id_factura_pivote: "6", cantidad_factura_pivote: "1", fecha_factura_pivote: "2018-09-19", … }
​
length: 3
```

In my case I have 4 elements, and only 3 are different to `0`, but it only brings or shows the data of `data` and not the calculation that I want to show to the user. It should be noted that if I do not use the `data.filter` and the`data.map` it brings me the correct data but it takes the 4 elements (unexpected result) because I only want the 3 (in this case) or the elements that are different to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax isn't right. Those commas are not doing anything, so your console is basically only returning the result of your `filter`. Those methods need to be chained.

```
data.filter((item) =>item.value_tax != 0)
           .map((item) => +item.value_tax )
           .reduce((acc, obj) => acc +
           (
              (((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity)) - ((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity) * Number(obj.discount)) / 100)) * Number(obj.calculate_tax))
           ) 
           -
           (
              (((Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity)) - (Number(obj.cost) * Number(obj.quantity) * Number(obj.discount)) / 100))
           ),
```

And even still, there's still a problem with how you're mapping the items in the array to become a number, and then trying to access `obj.cost` and `obj.quantity`. What are you trying to accomplish with the mapping?

Comment: Thanks for show me the error, the commas was one of my mistakes, but the really error was in the `.map`, was wrong when I used the `+item.valut_tax` because it's a correct way when its used with one value (not as I have it on my code, are multiple data), just like this:

`filter((item) =>item.qtyvalue > 2 && item.qtyvalue < 10)
                            .map((item) => item.qtyvalue)
                            .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);`

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you are using a single variable  `this.tax` ,so it be that `data.map` is overriding the value set by `data.filter` in this.tax